# FOL: Is it possible for a ≠ a for some term a?

Tags: first-order-logic

When looking at the semantics of First Order Logic, I'm wondering whether it's possible for there to be an interpretation whereby α ≠ α for some term α.

Assuming that α is a constant here, I am unsure of how to define a possible case for this. For if it is a constant, then V(α) should refer to some object of the domain (D). How could it be that V(α) were to refer to some different object?

Assuming that α is a variable, there are two cases, I suppose, at which to look at:

- bound variables
- free variables

In the case of the bound variable, it is not possible for α ≠ α, as ∀ α(α ≠ α).

In the case of the free variable, a *wff* such as Fα says nothing, as far as I'm aware, about the identity.

I am probably overcomplicating things here massively and if that is so please let me know. I reckon the answer is much simpler and I have merely increased the scope of the question needlessly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

$\forall x (x=x)$ is an axiom of [First order logic with equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).

If $c$ is an individual constant of the language, from the above axiom we may derive the instance :

> $c=c$.

According to the rules of the semantics for FOL, an interpretation $\mathcal I$ assigns to each constant symbol $c$ a member $c^I$ of the universe (domain) $I$
of the interpretation.

Thus, $c=c$ must hold in every interpretation $\mathcal I$, because $c^I=c^I$.